# Operation with pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Suppose two Series
`a = [1,2,3,4,5]`,
 `b = [60,7,80,9,100]`

I would like to create a new variable, which will be calculated as follows:
`C = a/b if b >10 else a/b +1`

I can do this by using list comprenhension by the following way:

`C = [a[i] \b[i] if b[i] > 10 else a[i] \b[i] +1 for i in range(len(b))]`

My Question is the following:

Is there another way (e.g using lambda,map,apply etc.) so as to avoid the for loop?
(Series a,b,c can also be part of a pd.Dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is divide values and add `1` by condition - convert mask to integers `1` and `0`:

```
c  = a/b + (b <=10).astype(int)
#alternative
#c  = a/b + (~(b > 10)).astype(int)
```

Or add array created by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
c  = a/b + np.where(b > 10, 0, 1)
```

If want divide 2 times it is also possible (should be a bit slowier in large data)

```
c  = pd.Series(np.where(b >10, a/b, a/b +1), index=a.index)
```

---

```
print (c)
0    0.016667
1    1.285714
2    0.037500
3    1.444444
4    0.050000
dtype: float64
```

**Setup**:

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
b = pd.Series([60,7,80,9,100])
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

a = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,100, size=100000))
b = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,100, size=100000))

In [322]: %timeit [a[i] /b[i] if b[i] > 10 else a[i] /b[i] +1 for i in range(len(b))]
3.08 s ± 84.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [323]: %timeit a/b + (b <=10).astype(int)
1.71 ms ± 44.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [324]: %timeit a/b + np.where(b > 10, 0, 1)
1.67 ms ± 66.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [325]: %timeit np.where(b >10, a/b, a/b +1)
2.7 ms ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [326]: %timeit pd.Series(np.where(b >10, a/b, a/b +1), index=a.index)
2.74 ms ± 21.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: 2nd and 3rd proposal seem to work fine. The problem with the first one is that it is linked to the spesific example, where you add 1. To generalize it, i would like to know any alternative  to do a given arithmetic operation between two series given a certain contrain. I undertand that your proposal with np.where works here because there is not an 'elif' statement.